# Can anyone help me identify this connector type?

Tags: connector, identification

**Please Help with connector identification**

Can anyone help me identify this connector type?

I is 2 pin, pitch I think is 0.8mm (I measure it to be 1mm between the outer part of the pins, I do not have the tools for more accurate measurment)
From side to side it is 3mm, and 1mm in height. I initially thought it was a type of JST, but after scouring the internet I have not found any matches. Not for JST or Molex or any other brand.

If anyone could help me identify it, I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: why did you post a picture of five connectors viewed from a distance instead of a closeup of one connector?

Comment: @jsotola  Perhaps the OP "borrowed" the image from elsewhere...

Comment: Yep. @jsotola is right. Tried taking a picture myself, but could not get a good one And thought the other connectors in the picture could help by adding other angles.

Comment: Looks like a wire to board. Similar to the pico-EZmate from Molex, However I was not able to ID the exact part. Here is a link to the EZmate data sheet. I believe this is similar. http://www.literature.molex.com/SQLImages/kelmscott/Molex/PDF_Images/987651-7111.pdf